# Complex Numbers - Finding Roots

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

Hi there I was wondering if someone could help me?
I am struggling to find the roots of the polynomial

$z^4+2z+3=0$

It is not a quadratic so can't use the quadratic formula so am not quite sure what to do. What is normally a good way to tackle complex polynomials of this form?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:**
I needed its roots to answer the question 67(f), but looks like it would be very difficult to find the reisudes from those singularities. I am guessing there might have been a mistake in the question and that they meant $x^2$:[image]

So wanted a way to do it without using wolfram alpha

Comment: Why do you need its [sick roots](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E4%2B2z%2B3)?

Comment: You can try https://mediacru.sh/xdemgsRCo3xK

Comment: @flawr Really cool. I would up vote you posted it as an answer.

Comment: I too suspect $x^2$ was meant. Do you mind saying what book is this from?

Comment: It was from a Hmk sheet at university but annoyingly that question didn't have a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a neat little trick which I stole from some chap named [Ferrari](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Ferrari.html). It works for all equations of the form $x^4 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, with the only difference being a completing-of-the-square at the first step. See [here](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Quadratic_etc_equations.html) for a reference (I chose this link because the story is almost as interesting as the maths!).

$$
\begin{align*}
z^4+2z+3&=0\\
\Rightarrow (z^2)^2&=-2z-3\\
\Rightarrow (z^2+y)^2&=-2z-3+2yz^2 + y^2&\forall\: y\\
&=(2y)z^2 - 2z + (- 3 + y^2)
\end{align*}
$$

Now the right hand side is a quadratic in $z$ and we can choose $y$ so that the right hand side has the form $(\alpha z+\beta)^2$. So, take the [almighty formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) and stipulate that $b^2-4ac=0$:
$$\begin{align*}
(-2)^2 -4(2y)(- 3 + y^2) &= 0\\
\Rightarrow4 + 24y - 8y^3 &= 0 \\
\Rightarrow1 + 6y - 2y^3 &= 0 
\end{align*}
$$
This is a cubic in $y$, which we can solve$^{\dagger}$. We get $y=-1.6418$, $y=-0.16825$ and $y=1.8100$. These values then mean you have the following formula, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are numbers dependent on our value of $y$.
$$
\begin{align*}
(z^2+y)^2&=(\alpha z+\beta)^2\\
\Rightarrow z^2+y&=\alpha z+\beta
\end{align*}
$$
Solve as usual.

---

$^{\dagger}$ Okay, I admit, I did this bit using Wolfram-Alpha...but you [*can* do it by hand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_polynomial), and it isn't too difficult. I am just running late for my tea...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a crazy attempt:

If you write down the equation as

$(z^2)^2 + 2z + 3 = 0$,

and you behave as if it's a quadratic polynomial $p(z)$, i.e. use the formula for quadratic equations, you would get that

$$z = \dfrac{-1 + \sqrt{1-3z^2}}{z^2}$$
$$z = \dfrac{-1 - \sqrt{1-3z^2}}{z^2}$$

Now, if you solve for $z$ in these equations you will get the solutions for the original equation.

Comment: No, it does not. If you checked the solutions of the equations I wrote, you would see that the roots are the same.

Comment: I figured out what you meant, the notation with $z1$ and $z2$ both used for meaning $z$ was really confusing. I've made a suggested edit which should make it more clear what you mean.

Comment: I don’t understand. You’re taking an equation of form $T^2+2z+3=0$ and saying it’s quadratic in ?

Comment: Darksonn: Understood, thanks for the edit;
@Lubin, I'm taking an equation in the form $az^2+bz+c$, only with the difference that $a$ is not a constant, but $a = z^2$. I don't really know if that is proper, but it seems to be working. I was hoping someone more knowledgeable than me would discuss the idea.

Comment: @Eutherpy Your idea works. It's not exactly helpful, but it is correct as per the following. For all $z\in \mathbb C$ with $z\neq 0$ and with a proper interpretation of $\sqrt \cdot$
$$\begin{align} 
z^4+2z+3=0&\iff z^2+\dfrac 2 z+\dfrac 3{z^2}=0\\
&\iff z^2+\dfrac 2 z=-\dfrac 3{z^2}\\
&\iff z^2+\dfrac 2 z+\dfrac 1{z^4}=\dfrac 1{z^4}-\dfrac 3{z^2}\\
&\iff \left(z+\dfrac 1{z^2}\right)^2=\dfrac{1-3z^2}{z^4}\\
&\iff z=-\dfrac 1{z^2}\pm \sqrt{\dfrac{1-3z^2}{z^4}}.
\end{align}$$
A discussion by cases yields what you wrote.